# SIGABRT @ [self.window addSubview:viewController.view]; on devices only

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib, xib, sigabrt

On the iPad/iPhone simulator, my app runs perfectly. On either device, I get a SIGABRT @ [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

The two XIB files (MainWindow.xib and appNameViewController.xib) seem set up correctly, but I suspect it's where the problem lies anyway (If I comment out adding the subView, the app loads on the devices). However, since it works fine in the simulator, it's hard to troubleshoot and I am looking for some tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but if you are manually loading the xib manually:

```
initWithName:bundle:
```

Check to make sure the cases are the same for the names. The device is case sensitive when accessing things.

Comment: I love you. Case sensitivity it was.